# Converting mp4 for Android and error Sorry, this video cannot be played

Tags: php, android, ffmpeg

I am trying to convert video to mp4 for android with this line:

```
$q = ''.$ffmpeg_path.' -i video.avi -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -preset slow -b:v 250k -maxrate 250k -bufsize 500k -vf scale="320" -threads 0 video.mp4'; 
echo "Command: ".$q."\n";
shell_exec($q);
$m = shell_exec($mp4box_path." -tmp /folder/ -inter 500 /folder/video.mp4");
```

But when I try to play video on my Nexus 5 , video is started and I can see maybe first 2-3 sec and than I have this error 
**Sorry, this video cannot be played**

Cant find solution for what the problem is on the net ,i am trying to change main and baseline profile in ffmpeg command but I get the same error.